# Pure console Android Application?

Tags: java, android, logging, android-emulator, console-application

Is it possible to create a pure console android application that will run in the android emulator?

I mean we can run classic desktop Java application that utilize `System.out.println` for console output, so I don't see why we are not able to do the same for Android via the `android.util.Log` classes.

The advantages of doing it on an emulator will be that gives access to the desired functionality implemented by Android Java classes.

Perhaps a dex file without the `Application`, `Activity` class and `AndroidManifest.xml`

How to best do this?

Comment: Your application must have a manifest, and as far as I'm aware if it doesn't specify a launcher activity it will either not compile or not do anything.  What do you expect would happen when running such an app anyway?  There's no built in console application for it to run in like there is on desktop OSes.  The Android system is designed to run apps that use activities, and services with no UI, not command-line programs.

Comment: Maybe something like a AndroidMain() method to do some processing with Log statements to write output to logcat, then terminate. Doesn't matter if its windowless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "AndroidMain" method.
You can accomplish this using a main Activity without UI or launching a Service.

E.g.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".MyService" />
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("MyService", "Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks too, but what about PURE console apps, like console packages installer via PackageManager, which can be started from android *console* via `pm install <appfile>` command, etc?