# Is it possible make pure console app in android

Tags: android

Can console app be made in android like PCs have black screen that can display text? App using only println() and  readLine(). Is it possible have with console gui?

Comment: Do you want to run it via the adb shell or are you asking about throwing a GUI front end that acts as a CLI?

Comment: I want GUI front end that acts as a CLI

Comment: There is nothing built into the Android SDK for that. You would need to try to find a library. https://github.com/Prokky/AsciiPanelView might handle your output.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked before: [Pure console Android Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39819703/pure-console-android-application)

I'll post the original question and accepted answer in case the link dies.

Question:

> Is it possible to create a pure console android application that will
> run in the android emulator?
>
> I mean we can run classic desktop Java application that utilize
> `System.out.println` for console output, so I don't see why we are not
> able to do the same for Android via the android.util.Log classes.
>
> The advantages of doing it on an emulator will be that gives access to
> the desired functionality implemented by Android Java classes.
>
> Perhaps a dex file without the `Application`, `Activity` class and
> `AndroidManifest.xml`
>
> How to best do this?

Accepted answer:

> There is no "AndroidMain" method. You can accomplish this using a main
> Activity without UI or launching a Service.
>
> E.g.
>
> AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".MyService" />
</application>
```

> MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
        startService(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

> MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    public MyService() {
        super("MyService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("MyService", "Hello world!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I posted this before you answered @spartygw. I thought you wanted to make a CLI-only app, hence the service.